# luaotfload: list available axes of variable font

Tags: fonts, luatex, luaotfload

Suppose I load a font via `luaotftool` like this

```tex
\font\MyFont="OpenSans:mode=node;" at 10pt
```

Now, I could find out whether this is a variable-weight font as follows:

```lua
\directlua{ local isVariableWeight = luaotfload.aux.provides_axis(\fontid\MyFont,'wght') }
```

I was wondering whether there's an easy way to list all font axes at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MWE below provides the necessary data. (To be compiled with LuaLaTeX, e.g. `lualatex mwe.tex`)

The key part is the "path" to the data:

```lua
luaotfload.fontloader.fonts.hashes.identifiers[<fontid>].resources.variabledata
```

[image: output]

```tex
\documentclass{article}

\directlua{ require 'mwe.lua' }

\font\MyFont="OpenSans:mode=node;" at 10pt

\begin{document}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\directlua{ PrintVariableData(\fontid\MyFont,5) }

\end{document}
```

```lua
-- file: mwe.lua
local indentsize = 10
function PairsByKeys(t, f) -- from https://www.lua.org/pil/19.3.html
    local a = {}
    for n in pairs(t) do table.insert(a, n) end
    table.sort(a, f)
    local i = 0
    local iter = function ()
        i = i + 1
        if a[i] == nil then return nil
        else return a[i], t[a[i]]
        end
    end
    return iter
end
function PrintTableRecursiveAux(t, indent, depth)
    if type(t) == 'table' then
        for k, v in PairsByKeys(t) do
            tex.sprint('\\hspace{' .. indent .. 'mm}\\verb|' .. tostring(k) .. '| \\texttt{=} \\verb|' .. tostring(v) .. '|\\par')
            if type(v) == 'table' and depth > 0 then
                PrintTableRecursiveAux(v, indent+indentsize, depth - 1)
            end
        end
    else
        tex.sprint('\\hspace{' .. indent .. 'mm}\\verb|' .. tostring(t) .. '|\\par')
    end
end
function PrintTableRecursive(t, depth)
    PrintTableRecursiveAux(t, 0, depth or 0)
end
function PrintVariableData(fontid, depth)
    local vardata = luaotfload.fontloader.fonts.hashes.identifiers[fontid].resources.variabledata
    PrintTableRecursive(vardata,depth or 1)
end
```

Comment: If someone knowledgeable on the topic could suggest a (perhaps less "hacky"?) way of accessing this data, I'd be very interested. Otherwise I'll just accept this answer of my own.